# How to reset my Static ViewModel from an ApplicationService Class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, datacontext

I have multiple Windows in my Project, to have only one Instance of an ViewModel Ive got this Class:

```
    public sealed class ApplicationService
    {
    private ApplicationService() { }

    public static ApplicationService Instance { get; } = new ApplicationService();

    public ModelView modelView { get; } = new ModelView();
    }
```

And in my Xaml Windows I declare my DataContext like this:

```
 DataContext="{Binding modelView, Source={x:Static local:ApplicationService.Instance}}"
```

*ModelView is in this Case the name of my ViewModel*

to acces my ViewModel in Code Behind I use this:

```
var vm = (ModelView)this.DataContext;
```

The Problem which Ive got now, is that the ViewModel never get Cleared, the Data stays there(I guess it is because of the **Static** Part).

Anyone an Idea on how to clear/reset the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method to the `ModelView` class that clears it and call this method, or add a setter to the property of the `ApplicationService` and assign it to a new instance:

```
public ModelView modelView { get; set; } = new ModelView();
```

**Clear:**

```
 ApplicationService.Instance.modelView = new ModelView();
```